# What is the largest number that divides $n^5-n$ whenever $n$ is odd?

Tags: number-theory

My attempt: Let $n=2k+1$, where $k$ is an Integer. Then $$n^5-n=(2k+1)(2k)2(k+1)2(2k^2+2k+1)=8(2k+1)(k)(k+1)(2k^2+2k+1)=16(2k+1)(P)(2k^2+2k+1)$$ 
where $P$ is an integer. So according to me the answer should be atleast $16$. How should I go about finding other factors from this expression. What other approaches can I use to solve problems of this kind?

Edit: This was a multiple choice question. The choices were:

1. 15
2. 30
3. 16
4. 240
5. 720

Comment: You are asking what the largest number *dividing* $n^5 - n$ is, not *divisible* by $n^5 - n$ (which wouldn’t exist as $k·(n^5 -n)$ increases without bounds for $k → ∞$). Then, you need to be more precise: The largest number dividing $n^5 - n$ is, of course, $n^5 - n$ itself. Are you searching for prime factors?

Comment: @k.stm Well, such a number does exist, but there's only one and it's very, very small :).

Comment: With the clarification from the OP, the problem is even more confusing. Seems like the question is "what is the largest number that is guaranteed to divide $n^5-n$ for ALL odd integers $n$".

Comment: You have made an edit, but your title still makes no sense. If you are looking for the $gcd$ of all integer numbers of the form $n^5-n$ with $n$ odd, it is $240$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio the answer is indeed 240. I've quoted the author of my textbook, while writing this problem. Please suggest a suitable edit so that the problem can be easily understood by everyone.

Answer (score 2):

With such problems, you should always factorize first and see if you can get anywhere from there. Also, plugging in specific values helps (do that with the factorized expressions). That already suffices here:

Okay, so let $N = n^5 - n = n·(n^4 - 1) = n·(n-1)·(n+1)·(n^2 + 1)$ for some $n ∈ ℕ$.

If $n$ is odd,

- all of $n-1$, $n+1$ and $n^2 + 1$ are even, one of $n-1$, $n+1$ even being divisible by $4$, so $N$ is divisible by $16$,
- one of $n$, $n-1$ and $n+1$ is divisible by $3$, so $N$ is divisible by $3$,
- either one of $n$, $n-1$ or $n+1$ is divisible by $5$ or else $n \equiv \pm 2 \bmod 5$, so $n^2 + 1 \equiv 5 \equiv 0 \bmod 5$, and $N$ is divisible by $5$.

So all numbers $N = n^5 - n$ with $n$ being odd are divisible by $16·3·5 = 240$.

For $n = 3$, $N = 3·2·4·10 = 240$, so there is no number larger than $240$ that divides *all* numbers $N = n^5 - n$ with $n$ being odd.

Comment: Notice that for $n = 1$, $n^5 - n = 0$ is divisible by all numbers, that’s why you have to go to the next smallest parameter $n = 3$ here.

Comment: In your third bullet, did you mean $n^2 + 1 \equiv 5$?

Comment: @arkeet Yes, fixed it. Thanks.